# How to decode the time variable while using xarray to load a NETCDF file

Tags: datetime, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a netcdf file giving monthly precipitation values from 1948 to 2008. The time variable has a format as below:

```
float time(time) ;
        time:units = "months since 1948-01-01 00:00:00" ;
        time:time_origin = "01-JAN-1948:00:00:00" ;
```

When i try to use Xarray to open the dataset using the following command

```
ds=xr.open_dataset("C:/Users/vsri/Downloads/prcp_monthly_1948-2008.nc")
```

I get the following error

```
ValueError: unable to decode time units 'months since 1948-01-01 00:00:00' with the default calendar. Try opening your dataset with decode_times=False.
```

If i use the decode_Times=False argument, the time variable has a floating point value assigned to it (as below)

```
 Coordinates:
      * longitude  (longitude) float32 0.25 0.75 1.25 1.75 ... 358.75 359.25 359.75
      * latitude   (latitude) float32 -89.75 -89.25 -88.75 ... 88.75 89.25 89.75
      * z       (z) float32 0.0
      * time (time) float32 0.0 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 ... 728.0 729.0 730.0 731.0
```

I do not want to use decode_Times=False becasue I cannot use the resample function of xarray on the dataset any more.

Can someone guide me on how to make sure that xarray reads the data set with the proper time stamp and not as a floating point ?

Comment: Note there is a difference between a "calendar month" and a ["month" defined by CF conventions](http://cfconventions.org/Data/cf-conventions/cf-conventions-1.7/cf-conventions.html#time-coordinate).  A calendar month varies in length depending on the specific month, while a month in CF conventions always has the same length.  Because of this discrepancy xarray elects not to try to automatically decode times with these units.  It is straightforward to work around this, however, so I should be able to provide an answer.  My guess is the units in this file correspond to calendar months?

Comment: @spencerkclark: Thanks for your clarification. In this case I am not sure if it matters as the data is one value per month. So 732 months in the time period 1948-2008. Apologies if I am not getting the concept correctly. What is the workaround for this issue Xarray ?

Comment: I got something similar while opening a opendap dataset. I fixed it by installing `cftime` which `xarray` was trying to import in the traceback.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks for the update in your comment.  In your case, since your data has a regular frequency, I recommend working around this by creating your own time coordinate with [`pandas.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```py
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.open_dataset("C:/Users/vsri/Downloads/prcp_monthly_1948-2008.nc", decode_times=False)
units, reference_date = ds.time.attrs['units'].split('since')
ds['time'] = pd.date_range(start=reference_date, periods=ds.sizes['time'], freq='MS')
```

This will create an array of dates for the first of each month starting in 1948-01-01 and ending the appropriate number of months later.

Comment: Do we know if the need to specify `decode_cf=False` is a result of how the original NetCDF data is released/packaged?

Comment: Yes, if `"months"` are specified as a time unit then xarray will raise an error if `decode_cf=True`, or more specifically, `decode_times=True`, so we need to specify `decode_times=False` when opening the file.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply and I appreciate the insight. Working with hycom specifically, and will add comments here for what I find to work best.